# Transitioning from WPF Windows 7 to UWP

Tags: wpf, windows-10, uwp

Im developing a Desktop app with WFP, but I've to migrate it to UWP Windows 10. Does anybody knows what this conversion involves? How complex is it?

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Not converting codebase, but you can repackage the binaries as UWP, there is a VS extension for it: http://mspoweruser.com/visual-studio-making-easier-convert-desktop-apps-uwp/

Answer (score 3):

XAML for WPF and WINRT is not same because lot of classes which exist for WPF are missing in WINRT library. So the porting may have lots of work to do.

This may be helpful to you: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-741

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to convert it from WPF to UWP be sure to keep an eye out for the next few things:

- ASync calls
- a framework with less options but same possibilities
- depends on your code and programme, but if you are experienced it might only take a few hours :)

Answer (score 0):

.NET in WinRT is a lot more limited than the one in WPF.
So the level of difficulty of porting directly depends to your app's functionality.